# HTML how to make a table auto expand to the window

Tags: html, html-table

I’m new to creating html tables, and I’ve pulled from various resources to create the following to list information from some test sensors.

What I’m struggling to do is have the full table auto expand to fill to the size of the users browser’s window. Currently it is a fixed width.

What has to be added to the header to allow both columns to expand/adjust?

My current codes is as follows.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         &lt;head&gt; &lt;meta http-equiv=&apos;refresh&apos; content=&apos;30&apos; /&gt; &lt;/head&gt;<br/>
         &lt;style&gt;.custom { font-size: 1em; font-family: Gill Sans Extrabold, sans-serif; padding:5px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; }
         &lt;/style&gt;
         &lt;table class=custom&gt;
         &lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;th class=custom&gt;Security Sensor
         &lt;/th&gt;
         &lt;th class=custom&gt;Last Tripped
         &lt;/th&gt;
         &lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
         &lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt;20. Living Room
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:47:52
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
         &lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt;18. Hallway
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:47:17
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
         &lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt;10. Kitchen
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:47:17
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
         &lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt;Kitchen - Motion Sensor
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:39:41
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
         &lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt;17. Entrance Hall
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:13:42
         &lt;/td&gt;
         &lt;/tr&gt;<br/>lt;tr class=custom&gt;
         &lt;td class=custom&gt;05. Ben&apos;s Room
         &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:13:26
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;02. Landing
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:13:22
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;03. Loft Landing
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:13:21
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;06. Loft Room
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 11:13:14
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;01. Front Door
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:38:47
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;08. Side Door
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:36:04
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;13. Conservatory
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:35:47
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;19. Front Room
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:35:15
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;12. Dining Room
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:34:36
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;07. Conservatory Door
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:32:13
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;04. Main Bedroom
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 10:23:57
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;09. Emma&apos;s Room&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/09 - 09:31:53
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;14. Kitchen Door
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2018/04/08 - 16:21:20
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;tr class=custom&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt;11. Lean To&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td class=custom&gt; 2017/12/16 - 12:20:04
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;<br/>
&lt;/table&gt;<br/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: table width = 100% ?

Comment: use <table width="100%">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the width in the class or directly in the table tag. You can also specify the width in td tag for give width to the table column

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 13px; 
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      }
     .custom { font-size: 1em; font-family: Gill Sans Extrabold, sans-serif; padding:5px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; } table { width:100% } .th { width:50% }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class=custom>
      <tr class=custom>
        <th class=custom>Security Sensor</th>
        <th class=custom>Last Tripped</th>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>20. Living Room</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:47:52</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>18. Hallway</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:47:17</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>10. Kitchen</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:47:17</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>Kitchen - Motion Sensor</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:39:41</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>17. Entrance Hall</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:13:42</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>05. Ben&apos;s Room</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:13:26</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>02. Landing</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:13:22</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>03. Loft Landing</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:13:21</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>06. Loft Room</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 11:13:14</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>01. Front Door</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 10:38:47</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>08. Side Door</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 10:36:04</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>13. Conservatory</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 10:35:47</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>19. Front Room</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 10:35:15</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      <tr class=custom>
        <td class=custom>12. Dining Room</td>
        <td class=custom> 2018/04/09 - 10:34:36</td>
      </tr>
      <br/>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will do the needful :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            table {
        border: thin solid black;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              The table only expands enough for the content inside of it.
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
    </body>
</html>
```